# Why Hadamard product appear in General backpropagation derivation?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I'm trying to understand the basic backpropagation of a neural network and stuck with this formula, which describes how you calculate the error vector for a layer $i$:

$$\delta z^{[i]} = (w^{[i + 1]})^{T} \delta z^{[i + 1]} \odot g'^{[i]}(z^{[i]})$$

Where matrix $W^{[i]}$ contains all weights of layer $i$ and $g'^{[i]}(z^{[i]})$ is the derivative of layer $l$ 's activation function at $z^{[i]}$. We call this equation **(1)**

This formula comes from this "unrigorous" derivation: Suppose we consider neural network with 3 layers and so, goes along with 3 parameters $(w^{[3]}, b^{[3]})$, $(w^{[2]}, b^{[2]})$, $(w^{[1]}, b^{[1]})$. Then, we'd like to calculate gradient for each layer to improve the cost.  In other words:

With $i = 3$: $\frac{\delta L}{\delta w^{[3]}}$ is the corresponding gradient.
$$\frac{\delta L}{\delta w^{[3]}} = \frac{\delta L}{\delta a^{[3]}} \frac{\delta a^{[3]}}{\delta z^{[3]}} \frac{\delta z^[3]}{\delta w^{[3]}} = \frac{\delta L}{\delta a^{[3]}} \frac{\delta a^{[3]}}{\delta z^{[3]}} a^{[2]}$$.

With $i = 2$:
$$\frac{\delta L}{\delta a^{[3]}} \frac{\delta a^{[3]}}{\delta z^{[3]}} \frac{\delta z^{[3]}}{\delta a^{[2]}} \frac{\delta a^{[2]}}{\delta z^{[2]}} a^{[1]} = \delta z^{[3]} w^{[3]} g'^{[2]}(z^{[2]})a^{[1]} = \delta z^{[2]} a^{[1]}$$, where we've just defined:

$$\delta z^{[2]} = \delta z^{[3]} w^{[3]} g'^{[2]}(z^{[2]})$$. And hence, By "rearranging things", we have the formula **(1)** mentioned above. Where does Hadamard product come into play? Isn't that just simple matrix operation?

My question: What is the intuition behind the formula **(1)**?

My math background is ill :D. It's just some basic linear algebra and calculus from university. Highly appreciate any help. Thanks :D